# Capture ALT+F4 inside a GTK application

Tags: ubuntu, gtk

Is there any way to capture shortcuts as <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd> within a GTK Ubuntu app? I intend to make a kiosk aplication and I'd like to avoid these keys from my app not at OS level to avoid to be closed by the user.

Comment: Perhaps catching the delete event is better, since this covers every case in which the user might try to close the app. http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/unstable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-delete-event

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> should be inhibited system-wide, not just in your app. This is IMHO best modified using GNOME's keybord shortcuts configuration program.

As about catching <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>, you should instead catch the delete-event, as Jong Bor already told you. If you need to lock more functions, give a look at [sabayon](http://library.gnome.org/users/sabayon/2.30/sabayon.html) and [pessulus](http://library.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/lockdown.html.en).
See also the [lockdown section of the GNOME Administration documentation](https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/dconf-lockdown.html.en).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Jong Bor's comment, but if you want to capture keypresses, you can do so with [Gtk::Widget::signal_key_press_event()](http://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/unstable/classGtk_1_1Widget.html#a5d011cc0cfa3993bc342ccff612c13ff).

To catch modifiers such as CTRL, ALT or SHIFT, you'll have to create a mask as follows:

```
// Mask will match when CTRL and SHIFT are both pressed
// ALT is usually equal to Gdk::MOD1_MASK
const GdkModifierType maskToMatch = (GdkModifierType)(GDK_SHIFT_MASK | GDK_SHIFT_MASK);
```

Comment: Will the event reach the OS or will the app consume it? I need the user to get blocked within the app without possibility to exit or logging off.

Comment: what about using `gdk.Window.add_filter` on root window?